# Run PHP script on Modal close

Tags: php, html

I have a modal that shows the user a video they have to watch as part of an online training course. I then have a PHP script that updates the database to mark the video as watched. It works, but right now I have a submit button that the user needs to click to run the PHP script, but I want it to run automatically when the modal is closed. Is there a way to do this?

The Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">GDPR & the Data Protection Act</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <video width="100%" autoplay muted preload="auto">
               <source src="Lesson1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The form for the submit button:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" name="complete">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Mark as Complete" />
</form>
```

Comment: Either don't allow the modal to be closed other than by submitting the form, or (better) attach some kind of event listener to the closure of the modal and use AJAX to update your database in the background.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And why is this question tagged with MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're using a Bootstrap Modal.
If that is your case, it's possible to set a watcher on the modal "close" event. Inside of that, you can call the php script, through an Ajax call:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // Ajax call to php script here
})
```

**Note** *Bootstrap v3 and v4 are using different names for the same "modal close" event: be sure to use the right one for your version!*

[Official documentation: Bootstrap Modals - Events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events)

Comment: Thank you! Thought that might be the case

Answer (score 0):

#### Solutions

1. Create backend php that update the database
2. Create onclick listener to the modal close button

   - Inside the onclick function, try to use ajax to called the backend php that you
     had created on step 1.

Hopes that its help. Happy coding.